# Magento 1.9 CE - Bundesland deaktivieren / disable state/province select

Tags: magento-1.9, state

seit CE 1.7 ist es eigentlich möglich, unter Allgemein -> Bundeslandoptionen die Abfrage nach dem Bundesland zu deaktivieren. Auch in 1.8.0.1 war das noch möglich. Jetzt habe ich eine 1.9.0.1 Installation und dort ist dieser Bereich nicht mehr vorhanden...

Wurde es verschoben, oder ist es in der aktuellen 1.9 nicht mehr möglich, das Bundesland zu deaktivieren?

Danke

---

since 1.7 it is possible to deactivate the state/province dropdown in general -> State options. But in 1.9 this Tab isn't any more there... has it moved?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my CE1.9 installation there is still an option under Configuration=>General, but its only available for the Default config.

This are the options that I have available in State Options:
 [image: State Options]

Comment: You're right! Damn... The translation files are not really great :(

Answer (score 1):

In Mage_Directory.csv is a wrong translation of State...

[image: Wrong translation of State in Mage_Directory.csv]

Comment: You should consider using the [German community translation](https://github.com/riconeitzel/German_LocalePack_de_DE).